# Передача переменой php в javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Подключил шаблон админки https://colorlib.com/polygon/cooladmin/chart.html
Хочу использовать диаграмму DoughutChart который идет в составе с шаблоном. Мне нужно передать значения переменных в js чтобы отобразить эти значения на диаграмме. Как это сделать?

```js
(function ($) {
  // USE STRICT
  "use strict";

  try {

    //doughut chart
    var ctx = document.getElementById("doughutChart");
    if (ctx) {
      ctx.height = 150;
      var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'doughnut',
        data: {
          datasets: [{
            data: [45, 25, 20, 10], // сюда вместо этих значений передать переменные $moboblock, $stac, $laptop, $netbook
            backgroundColor: [
              "rgba(0, 123, 255,0.9)",
              "rgba(0, 123, 255,0.7)",
              "rgba(0, 123, 255,0.5)",
              "rgba(0,0,0,0.07)"
            ],
            hoverBackgroundColor: [
              "rgba(0, 123, 255,0.9)",
              "rgba(0, 123, 255,0.7)",
              "rgba(0, 123, 255,0.5)",
              "rgba(0,0,0,0.07)"
            ]

          }],
          labels: [
            "Моноблоки",
            "Стационарные",
            "Ноутбуки",
            "Нетбуки"
          ]
        },
        options: {
          legend: {
            position: 'top',
            labels: {
              fontFamily: 'Poppins'
            }

          },
          responsive: true
        }
      });
    }


  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }


})(jQuery);
```

```html
<?php
// ORM - RedBeans
// Получаем количество записей по условию
$monoblock = \R::count('uchet_comps', "name = 'Моноблок'");
$stac = \R::count('uchet_comps', "name = 'Стационарный компьютер'");
$laptop = \R::count('uchet_comps', "name = 'Ноутбук'");
$netbook = \R::count('uchet_comps', "name = 'Нетбук'");
?>

<div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="au-card m-b-30">
        <div class="au-card-inner">
            <h3 class="title-2 m-b-40">Doughut Chart</h3>
            <canvas id="doughutChart"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cookies, GET parameters, file_put_contents(), WebSockets.

Comment: Можно в шаблоне задать глобальные JS переменные и подставить в них значения в средствами PHP. После загрузки HTML кода в браузер значения этих переменных станут доступны любому JS коду на странице.

Comment: @e_v_medvedev спасибо, ваш комментарий мне помог

Comment: тогда не забывайте плюсовать репутацию :-) . И обращайтесь еще.